# Refresh Listbox from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

This is the program I have:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that once I click "Add Event", then the listbox of events is refreshed (as you can see, it is in the main form). Normally when the main form loads the list is refreshed (loaded from .txt file) and I have a method for it in separate class (C)..

```
    public static void DisplayOnlyEvents(ListBox lstOutput)
    {
        //clear listbox first            
        lstOutput.Items.Clear();
        string output;

        //output data 
        foreach (Event Event in frmMainWindow.AllExistingEvents)
        {
                    output = (Event.getDescription());
                    lstOutput.Items.Add(output);


        }
    }
```

Clearly this method requires passing a listbox from main from into it, in order for it to work. But how can I pass a listbox that is in form A from form B into a method that is in class C?

If you need more information, please ask. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, ironically, you can use Events/Eventhandling to solve your problem.

Comment: do a google search on how to pass params to a different form Google is a life saver if used properly.. check out this free b as well https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7e9f80c-5144-4ad9-aa5e-7803363ae0cd/passing-variables-between-forms

Answer (score 0):

In your `Form1` class, create a static variable that will reference your `ListBox`

```
    public static ListBox ListBoxRef;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBoxRef = this.lstOutPut;
        ...
    }
```

Then in your `Form2`:

```
ClassC.DisplayOnlyEvents(Form1.ListBoxRef);
```